# VBScript FileExists fails consistantly

Tags: asp.net, iis, vbscript, file-exists

We're trying to read some log files for our application but FileExists is failing in every case.  So I simplified the problem with this test code:

```
Dim filespec, msg
filespec = Chr(34) & "C:\Windows\explorer.exe" & Chr(34) 
'filespec = "C:\Windows\explorer.exe" 
'filespec = Chr(34) & "C:" & Chr(34) 
'filespec = "C:"
'filespec = "default.asp"
 Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 If (fso.FileExists(filespec)) Then
     msg = filespec & " exists."
 Else
  msg = filespec & " doesn't exist."
 End If
 Response.Write(msg)
```

As you can see, we've tried testing with and without added Chr(32) (which is the double quote character).  We're testing against the file C:\Windows\explorer.exe  and the file C:\Windows\explorer.exe does exist on the computer hosting the asp files and the iis server.  We even fail when simply checking to see if the C drive exist.

Additionally, it even fails if we try to see if the default.asp file exists and that file is in the same directory as our filetest.asp file.

Does anyone see why our FileExists is consistently failing?  Thank you.

Comment: An interesting addition:  checking for a folder will work 
 Dim NewFolder
 NewFolder = "C:\Windows"
 If (fso.FolderExists(NewFolder)) Then
   msg = NewFolder & " exists."
 Else
   msg = NewFolder & " doesn't exist."
 End If
 Response.Write(msg)
 Response.Write("<br>")
 
But checking for files inside a folder which has been shown to exists still fails.

Comment: Oddly enough, now  filespec = "C:\Windows\explorer.exe" will work.  But looking for the default.asp in the same directory won't.

Comment: Don't use additional quotes or `Chr(34)`. They're not needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
filespec = "C:\Windows\explorer.exe"
```

Without the additional quotes will work.  To find a folder we need to use

```
 fso.FolderExists
```

Instead of FileExists.

This still doesn't find the default.asp file in the same directory.  But that problem is too far removed from our actual problem which is to look at log files on another drive.  That problem is too far from this original question so I'll post that problem separately.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try to load the folder in to a folder object and loop through files in the folder object.  Below is an example.

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

FileToFind = "explorer.exe"
FolderToSearch = "C:\Windows\"

Set myFolder = fso.GetFolder(FolderToSearch)

For each myFile in myFolder.Files

    If myFile.Name = FileToFind Then 
        Wscript.echo "Found " & myFolder.Path & "\" & myFile.Name
    End If

Next
```

Answer (score 0):

you do not need to insert additional quotes. removing your quotes will work just fine.

```
 Dim filespec, msg

 filespec = "C:\Windows\explorer.exe" 

 Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 If (fso.FileExists(filespec)) Then
     msg = filespec & " exists."
 Else
     msg = filespec & " doesn't exist."
 End If

 Response.Write(msg)
```

In the past, I have only noticed that you need to insert additional quotes when using the wshshell.run since a space might be interpreted as additional arguments to the filename.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that our problem is not in the VBScript at all.  The app is running inside an ApplicationPool in iis.  The Identity property of that Application Pool is the dynamically created applicationPoolIdentity user.  This is a user with no permissions.  So essentially, the application is running as a user which does not have access to any other drives.  Therefore, it cannot find any file on any network drive.  We will have to create an additional identity with the proper rights and set our applicationPool identity to use that custom account.

I found instructions on how to set this identity account here:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771170%28v=ws.10%29.aspx